# Split one big abstract class into multiple ones + inherit from it

Tags: typescript, oop

Basically, I have ONE main base abstract class that currently implements methods that will need to be split into different classes (`getTestA1`,`getTestA2` need to be on one class and `getTestB1`,`getTestB2` need to be on **another**, etc)

`ChildClass` will then need to have all of said methods available inside.

I currently have the following structure:

```js
export abstract class AbstractBase {

    // I'M ABSTRACT, I NEED TO BE IMPLEMENTED BY MY CHILDREN
    protected abstract httpRequest: TestType;

    // I WILL CALL MY ABSTRACT METHOD INSIDE
    public request = (...someArgs) => {

        // I'M CALLING MY ABSTRACT METHOD
        return this.httpRequest({
          method,
          url,
          body: requestContext.body as string,
        }).then((response) => {
          responseContext.resolve(response);
        });
    }

    // THE FOLLOWING METHODS ALL CALL this.request INSIDE
    public getTestA1 = function() {
       ...
       this.request(...args);
    }

    public getTestA2 = function() {
       ...
       this.request(...args);
    }

    public getTestB1 = function() {
       ...
       this.request(...args);
    }

    public getTestB2 = function() {
       ...
       this.request(...args);
    }
}

export class ChildClass extends AbstractBase {
  protected static readonly defaultConfig = {
    ...
  };

  // HERE I AM, IMPLEMENTING MY ABSTRACT METHOD
  protected httpRequest: ClientHTTPRequest = (input) => {
    ...
    return fetch(input.url, {
      method: input.method,
      headers: input.headers,
      body: input.body,
    }).then((res) => {
      ...
    });
  };
}
```

I was directed to use mixins by someone here (they even closed my original question as a possible duplicate), but the fact that this is an **abstract** class makes this way more confusing to me :/

My requirements are:

1. `AbstractBase` will need to be split into different classes
2. `ChildClass` will need to inherit (or use multiple mixins) from those different classes

How is this achievable? 
I'm a bit lost on this one.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR**

```js
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
  baseCtors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach((name) => {
      Object.defineProperty(
        derivedCtor.prototype,
        name,
        // @ts-ignore
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name),
      );
    });
  });
}

export class ChildClass {
  protected httpRequest = (input) => {
     ...
  };
}

export interface ChildClass extends AbstractBase {}
applyMixins(ChildClass, [AbstractBase]);
```

**Result:**

```js
const test = new ChildClass();

// test.getTestA1 is not a function
```

I've also tried the following:

```js
class Multi {
  // Inherit method to create base classes.
  static inherit(..._bases) {
    class Classes {
      // The base classes
      get base() {
        return _bases;
      }

      constructor(..._args) {
        var index = 0;

        for (let b of this.base) {
          let obj = new b(_args[index++]);
          Multi.copy(this, obj);
        }
      }
    }

    // Copy over properties and methods
    for (let base of _bases) {
      Multi.copy(Classes, base);
      Multi.copy(Classes.prototype, base.prototype);
    }

    return Classes;
  }

  // Copies the properties from one class to another
  static copy(_target, _source) {
    for (let key of Reflect.ownKeys(_source)) {
      if (key !== 'constructor' && key !== 'prototype' && key !== 'name') {
        let desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(_source, key);
        Object.defineProperty(_target, key, desc);
      }
    }
  }
}

export class ChildClass extends Multi.inherit(AbstractBase) {
   ...
}
```

**Result:**

```js
const test = new ChildClass();

// test.httpRequest is not a function
```

Comment: Could you explain the problem you are trying to solve rather than the design you are attempting to implement? You seem to just want to be able to reuse a specific `httpRequest` implementation across multiple classes?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @plalx. Well, I didn't add this detail (as I didn't want to confuse my question even more), but I also have `ChildClass2` that implements its own (different than `ChildCass`) `httpRequest`. But I think you're right: I don't want to enforce the design I envisioned if it's wrong. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the nature of the classes. Are you implementing various facades (client) for an HTTP API? E.g. the `ChildClass` is the service/façade allowing responsible for abstracting the remote calls? What was the motivation for splitting the façade across many classes? It would help if we knew what real world domain these classes are part of and which problem they solve.

Comment: `ChildClass` (& `ChildClass2`) is the class responsible for implementing the actual `httpRequest` function (overriding the abstract function from (`AbstractClass`). That's very easy to do by just: `class ChildClass extends AbstractClass` and `class ChildClass2 extends AbstractClass`. The difficulty now lies with the need for splitting `getTestA1` / `getTestA2` into its own class (think `Booking` package) & `getTestB1` / `getTestB2` into its own class (think `Notification` package). Something like that.

Comment: Have you seen https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Mix-ins

Comment: @matthelliwell thanks for your comment. I did try the mixin approach that TypeScript recommends (first example under "What I've tried so far").

Comment: Is there any reason why `Booking` and `Notification` features should be mixed in same service class? Also, why inheritance? Can't you just have a `BookingService` and a `NotifcationService` taking an `httpRequest` as a constructor dependency? That would also make it trivial to compose larger facades from these stateless services.

Comment: Regarding your point on  `Booking` and `Notification`, yep, that's why I will need to separate the bigger `AbstractClass` into multiple classes (by your comment, no need for being `abstract` even!) Thanks, makes a lot of sense! I will give that a try.

Comment: @PetSilv e.g. `class BookingService { private request: HttpRequest; }` and `class NotificationService { private request: HttpRequest; }`. You can construct both services with distinct or the same `HttpRequest` implementation and there's no inheritance in the model.

Comment: @plax: My only issue is: By requirement, and this is really a requirement - because we need to provide one single object / class, `ChildClass` needs to have all methods from `BookingService`, `NotificationService` etc. `ChildClass` is a wrapper for all different services.

Regarding different `httpRequest`. To be clear: `ChildClass` will have one type (and their `Booking` / `Notification` etc will all have the same). `ChildClass2` will have another type of `httpRequest` etc.